# Filter [[String]] with custom range

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, compare

I want to prove if my array

```
let actualSigns = ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
```

... is equal to one of the arrays inside this one...

```
var validSigns = [[String]]()
validSigns.append(["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd"]) // want to match this
validSigns.append(["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Xy"]) // ... and this
validSigns.append(["Ee", "Ff", "Gg", "Hh"])
```

... by comparing only the number of objects of `actualSigns`.

So in this case, I want to match the first and second array in `validSigns`, because the first three values are equal to `actualSigns`.

I tried filtering it

```
let range = Range(start: actualSigns.count, end: actualSigns.count+1)
let match = validSigns.filter{ $0.removeRange(range) == actualSigns }
```

But the compiler says `'$0 is a let constant'`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does order matter? Will every element in a single array be unique? Will the array to match always be at the same position - i.e.: always at the beginning or the end of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startsWith` like this on the array you want to test.

```
let match = validSigns.filter{$0.startsWith(actualSigns)}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, haven't used `startsWith()` before.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric. Works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but you don't need to use range to get a match:

```
// My original answer
let match = validSigns.filter { !zip($0, actualSigns).contains { $0.0 != $0.1 } }

// Based on Price Ringo's answer
let match = validSigns.filter { $0.startsWith(actualSigns) }
```

Output:

```
[["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd"], ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Xy"]]
```

Comment: Thank you Eendje! Your original answer worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your error by doing:

```
let match = validSigns.filter{ var input = $0; input.removeRange(range); return input == actualSigns }
```

A few other methods, just for completeness:

```
import Foundation

let actualSigns = ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
var validSigns = [
  ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd"],
  ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Xy"],
  ["Ee", "Ff", "Gg", "Hh"],
  ["Ee", "Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]] // Added another case, to test when the matching array is not at the start

let matches = validSigns.filter { $0.joinWithSeparator("").containsString(actualSigns.joinWithSeparator("")) }
// => [["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd"], ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Xy"], ["Ee", "Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]]

let matches2 = validSigns.filter { Set($0).intersect(Set(actualSigns)).count == actualSigns.count }
// => [["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd"], ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Xy"], ["Ee", "Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]]
```